# ExtJs Handling Async Call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, extjs, extjs3

We are using extjs 3.2.1 JavaScript Framework. In one of the grid panel have an action menu on top. Based on the value retrieved from the database, I need to show or hide the menu. I can use the hidden property of the menu for that purpose.

The problem is the function I use to retrieve the value from database runs asynchronously and takes time to retrieve the value and by the time it returns the menu is already initialized. Here are both methods.

```
employeeProfile: function(profileType) {
    CR.Controllers.Employee.GetProfile(function(result) {
        if (CR.CRError.ParseResult(result)) {
            switch (profileType) {
                case "IsStandardAllowed":
                    return result.IsStandardAllowed === 1 ? true : false;
                case "IsUploadAllowed":
                    return result.IsUploadAllowed === 1 ? true : false;
                case "IsCopyAllowed":
                    return result.IsCopyAllowed === 1 ? true : false;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }, this);
},

getMenuActions:
function() {
    return [
        // add button
        new CR.EmployeePanelAction({
            text: this.lang_newFromStandard,
            tooltip: this.lang_tipNewFromStandard,
            handler: this.onNewFromTemplate,
            hidden: this.EmployeeProfile("IsStandardAllowed")
            scope: this
        }),
        new CR.EmployeePanelAction({
            text: this.lang_newFromUpload,
            tooltip: this.lang_tipNewFromUpload,
            handler: this.onNewFromUpload,
            hidden: this.employeeProfile("IsUploadAllowed"),
            scope: this
        }),
        new CR.EmployeePanelAction({
            text: this.lang_newFromCopy,
            tooltip: this.lang_tipNewFromCopy,
            handler: this.onNewFromCopy,
            hidden: this.employeeProfile("IsCopyAllowed"),
            scope: this
        })
    ];
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I didn't understand JavaScript Callback and Scope. I passed the callback method to the database retrieval method along with scope and it is working fine. Here is the method that I use to retrieve successfully.

```
isImageActionAllowed: function(setImageActions, scope) {
        MVC.Controllers.Users.GetUserProfile(function(result) {
            if(MVC.Error.ParseResult(result)) {
                setImageActions.call(scope, result);
            }
        }, this);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Ext.Button.hide()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Button-method-hide), Available since: 1.1.0

Should be working for you, unless there is a breaking bug in 3.2.1.

Comment: It works if I set hidden true or false. The issue is I have to get the value from database, whether I have to hide or not. The database call runs async and returns after the menu is initialized already

Comment: @MuthuAnnamalai Using the `hide()` function, you can hide or show the component after it has been initialized, so where exactly is your problem?

Comment: After initializing I tried to access the this.getMenuActions[0].hidden = value from database, didn't work for me. I really don't know where I am making mistake.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `getMenuActions` returns a config object, from which ExtJS somehow (not shown in your code) **derives** components. Once these components are created based on the config object, you have to change the components, not the config object. And keep in mind to never change a config option of a component, if a similarly named function is available (i.e. always prefer `hide()` over `hidden = true`), because under the hood, other changes may be required, which the Sencha team should have taken care for in the function code.